# How to show valid label depending on a variable when it is true and show an error label when the variable is false

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I'm working on a project on node-red where a variable that comes from the Database is passed to a page, and it creates a page that should have a valid message(for example: green label with valid text) if the variable is true and an error message (for example: red label with error text) if the variable is false.

The page also is expected to hide the message (either valid or error) after 5 seconds, and be ready to receive another instance of this variable.

The code I developed only work on the first instance of the variable, And the page should receive this variable countless times and show if it is valid or error.

Note: For some reason in node-red, I can't access this variable inside script tag, it is accessible only inside the html code (`<body>`)

Here is the code I wrote:

*Hint: msg.payload is the variable I'm talking about.

```
<head>
  <style>
    .button1 {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
    .button2 {background-color: #f44336;} /* Red */
    .button3 {background-color: #ffffff;}   /* white */
  </style>
</head>
<body> 
    <span id="lbl2"  ng-class="{button1:msg.payload== true, button2:msg.payload== false}">validation message! 
    <script>setTimeout(function({document.getElementById("lbl2").style.backgroundColor="#ffffff";
              document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "";},5000)</script>
    </span> 
</body>
```

Comment: Which template node are you using? The `node-red-dashboard` version or the one included in the core nodes?

Comment: yes! I'm using the **ui_template** node of the dashboard.

Comment: The ui_template node should not have `<head>` or `<body>` tags, it's for an insert into a page, not a whole page.

Comment: I just knew that now. Do you think that's the problem?!

Comment: I can't use the other template node .. Is there a solution to the actual problem in Html, javascript?! because those which I can write in the template node

Comment: You need to look at how to use Angular